# How to create a regular expression with multiple conditions?

Tags: python, regex

If I want to match strings that start with a letter and are followed by either one or two numbers, I can do:

```
import re

re.match("^[A-Z][0-9]{1,2}$"
```

In my case, however, I have two more conditions:

- if there is a 0 after the letter, there must be a second number, so `E01` is fine, `E0` is not allowed
- if there is a 0 after the letter, there cannot be a second 0, so `E00` is not allowed.

Can one capture this in a single regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may be a solution.

```
re.match('[A-Z](?:0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]?)$', 'A09')
```

Comment: Almost, I guess, it also works for `'A100'` but only two numbers are allowed.

Comment: @Cleb I made 1 change to correct that case by adding `$` to the end of the regex.

Comment: That seems to do the trick, nice! Upvoted; I'll wait with the acceptance for a bit in case something else shows up...

Comment: @Ivar The beginning of string, `^`, indicator is not needed for `match` - it requires the match to begin at the beginning of the string. (I wrongly assumed that it needed to end which it doesn't so thats why the `$` is required). If using `search`, the beginning of the match could be anywhere in the string and `search` would need the `^` to start at the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid problems by using a single assertion `(?!.00?$)` for the conditions
then match normal letter plus 1 or 2 numbers `\d{1,2}`.
This spreads the responsibility for validation.

```
^(?!.00?$)[A-Z]\d{1,2}$
```

Note that `(?!.00?$)` only validates if 1 or 2 numbers at end, it
will not be just a 0 or a 00.
The `[A-Z]\d{1,2}` validates a letter plus restricts end to 1 or 2 numbers.
Together they syncronize validashun.

Comment: Seems to work fine as well for all cases I tested (upvoted). Could you explain it in more detail, please?

Comment: sure, added sum explaning

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the first part `?!.00?$` in more detail? for example, why is the `.` required although we only want to check letters and numbers?

Comment: @Cleb without the `.`, the negative lookahead would test if the string `^00?$` was not there, the lookahead begins at the beginning of the string so that just checks that the string `00` or `0` isn't the complete string. You need the `.` to represent the first char of the string.

Comment: @ChrisCharley: thanks for the additional explanation, regular expressions have never been my strength ;) I guess for me it is still not entirely clear why it also fails for only 0 zero and not just two 0s.

Comment: @Cleb I too am walking carefully around regexes. It fails for one zero as well as two because of the `?` following the second 0 (which makes the second zero optional).

Comment: @Cleb Corrected my previous (deleted) comment. `re.match('[A-Z](?!00?$)\d{1,2}$', 'A01')`

Comment: @ChrisCharley: Ah, that's the trick then indeed, thanks! Also thanks for the slightly modified version; I will probably go with your post though as that one was easier to understand for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
^(?:[A-Z]0[1-9]|[A-Z][1-9]|[A-Z][1-9][0-9])$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UFcX9C/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simle solution in python:

```
pattern = r"^[A-Z]{1}([0]{1}[1-9]{1})|([1-9]{1}[0-9]{1})$"
text = 'E01'
is_match = re.match(pattern, text) is not None
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.